# How to serve static files very fast?

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, varnish

I'm looking for a solution need to serve a few XML files to as many users as possibly. My current solution are static files and a Nginx server. The files a small so I could them also hold in memory.

Does everyone have a good solutions?

Comment: nginx is extremely fast when serving static files.  some benchmarks show that it serves static files even faster than blobs from `memcached` when the filesystem is given enough RAM to cache everything.

Answer (score 5):

Using Nginx seems reasonable. Just make sure the server has an adequate amount of RAM, hopefully enough to hold your entire set of XML files. As they get served, the OS kernel will automatically cache these files in memory, allowing them to be served very quickly.

Answer (score 1):

[Lighttpd](http://www.lighttpd.net/) is a good option for speedy serving of static files, as well.